# How can I add SSL encryption to available TCP/IP socket

Tags: c#, sockets, ssl, sslstream

I am going to upgrade a system which used TCP connection without SSL. I want to add SSL encryption to the current connection without changing much in code. This is what there was previously in the code.

```
IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(IpAddress);
IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, Port);

// Create a TCP/IP socket.
var client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
```

What I tried is this,

```
IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(IpAddress);
IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, Port);

// Create a TCP/IP socket.
var client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

client.BeginConnect(remoteEP, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
while (!client.Connected) { }
NetworkStream stream = new NetworkStream(client);
SslStream ssl = new SslStream(stream, false, ValidateServerCertificate);
```

But this is not doing what I need. At least `ValidateServerCertificate` delegate is not called. 
What's wrong with my code?
**IMPORTANT**
I cannot remove this socket named `client` during the change because it will affect lot of other codes.

Comment: "But this is not doing what I need" - What is it doing? Whats happening?

Comment: It creates the connection. It is not secured. "At least ValidateServerCertificate delegate is not called. "